# Mysql Recursive last ancestor function

Tags: mysql, function, recursion

I have a database table menu having id, parent_id and growth_on.

```
id parentid  growth_on
1   null       lft
2     1        lft
3     1        rght
4     2        lft
5     2        rght
```

is a binary tree , where `growth_to` indicates which way the branch grew, right or left.

I need to get the last ancestor branch according to the selected branch and side.

For example:

last ancestor from right side from id 1 = 3

last ancestor from lft side from id 1 = 4 (because his parent_id, 2, are growth on lft too).

I need specify wich side recursive function will map, creating a direct line from inputed id to last ancestor.

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: I 've been reading , but I need a different behavior , there are sides that the branches can grow

Comment: Nested model data structure not works form me, because i need pass wich tree 'side' will grow.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.